# Java built-in HttpClient doesn't remove subscribers fast enough

Tags: java, java-17, java-http-client, java-19

I have the following code:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import picocli.CommandLine;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@CommandLine.Command(name = "red-alert-listener",
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
        versionProvider = Listener.class,
        showDefaultValues = true,
        description = "An App that can get \"red alert\"s from IDF's Home Front Command.")
public class Listener implements Runnable, CommandLine.IVersionProvider
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER = new JsonMapper()
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
            .findAndRegisterModules();
    private static final Configuration DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION = new Configuration(
            false,
            false,
            true,
            false,
            Duration.ofMillis(10000),
            LanguageCode.HE,
            Level.INFO,
            Collections.emptySet()
    );
    private static final HttpClient HTTP_CLIENT = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    private Configuration configuration = DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION;
    private List<String> districtsNotFound = Collections.emptyList();

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        System.exit(new CommandLine(Listener.class)
                .setCaseInsensitiveEnumValuesAllowed(true)
                .execute(args));
    }

    private static void sleep()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException)
        {
            interruptedException.printStackTrace(); // TODO think about
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getVersion()
    {
        return new String[]{"Red Alert Listener v" + getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()};
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.err.println("Preparing Red Alert Listener v" + getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion() + "...");
        try (Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(Stream.of(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()).parallel().unordered()
                .filter(mixerInfo -> "default [default]".equals(mixerInfo.getName()))
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null));
             AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/alarmSound.wav"))));
             InputStream in = System.in)
        {
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            final URI uri = URI.create("https://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alert/alerts.json");
            Set<String> prevData = Collections.emptySet();
            Instant currAlertsLastModified = Instant.MIN;
            final int minRedAlertEventContentLength = """
                    {"cat":"1","data":[],"desc":"","id":0,"title":""}""".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
            System.err.println("Listening...");
            while (true)
                try
                {
                    final HttpResponse<InputStream> httpResponse = HTTP_CLIENT.send(
                            HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)
                                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                    .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                                    .header("Referer", "https://www.oref.org.il/12481-" + configuration.languageCode().name().toLowerCase() + "/Pakar.aspx")
                                    .timeout(configuration.timeout())
                                    .build(),
                            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream()
                    );

                    try (InputStream httpResponseBody = httpResponse.body())
                    {
                        if (httpResponse.statusCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK/* &&
                                httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED*/)
                        {
                            LOGGER.error("Connection response status code: {}", httpResponse.statusCode());
                            sleep();
                            continue;
                        }
                        final Instant alertsLastModified;
                        final long contentLength = httpResponse.headers().firstValueAsLong("Content-Length").orElse(-1);
                        if (contentLength < minRedAlertEventContentLength)
                            prevData = Collections.emptySet();
                        else if ((alertsLastModified = httpResponse.headers().firstValue("Last-Modified")
                                .map(lastModifiedStr -> DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.parse(lastModifiedStr, Instant::from))
                                .filter(currAlertsLastModified::isBefore)
                                .orElse(null)) != null)
                        {
                            currAlertsLastModified = alertsLastModified;

                            final RedAlertEvent redAlertEvent = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(
                                    httpResponseBody,
                                    RedAlertEvent.class
                            );
                            LOGGER.debug("Original event data: {}", redAlertEvent);
                        }
                    } catch (JsonParseException e)
                    {
                        LOGGER.error("JSON parsing error: {}", e.toString());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    LOGGER.debug("Got exception: {}", e.toString());
                    sleep();
                }
        } catch (Throwable e)
        {
            LOGGER.fatal("Closing connection and exiting...", e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private enum LanguageCode
    {
        HE,
        EN,
        AR,
        RU;
    }

    private record RedAlertEvent(
            int cat,
            List<String> data,
            String desc,
            long id,
            String title
    )
    {
    }

    private record Configuration(
            boolean isMakeSound,
            boolean isAlertAll,
            boolean isDisplayResponse,
            boolean isShowTestAlerts,
            Duration timeout,
            LanguageCode languageCode,
            Level logLevel,
            Set<String> districtsOfInterest
    )
    {
    }
}
```

My dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
        <artifactId>picocli</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.ashr123</groupId>
        <artifactId>time-measurement</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm using **OpenJDK 19** but it happens also on OpenJDK 17.

This is the most minimal code I can show you that demonstrate the problem.

When I used IntelliJ's profiler tool, I saw [image: this image] and here is a live CPU and heap charts (over 3 days): [image]
I think that my `HttpClient` doesn't close the subscriptions fast enough (i.e. it adds `HttpBodySubscriberWrapper` via `jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl#registerSubscriber` faster that it removes it via `jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl#subscriberCompleted`).

1. Why does it happen?
2. Why even though I've put the `Closeable` body in try-with-resources block doesn't remove the subscriber in time for the next loop?
3. How can I control the size of the subscriber field?
4. Can I demand in any way that there is only 1 "uncompleted" subscriber?

###### UPDATE

I've discovered that for `HttpResponse.BodyHandlers#ofString` it doesn't happen (subscriber list is always of size 1), so the question is why if I keep the body in try-with-resources it and close the `InputStream`, it doesn't removes the request's subscriber?

From `HttpResponse.BodySubscribers#ofInputStream` javadoc:

> API Note:
> To ensure that all resources associated with the corresponding exchange are properly released the caller must ensure to either read all bytes until EOF is reached, or call InputStream.close if it is unable or unwilling to do so. Calling `close` before exhausting the stream may cause the underlying HTTP connection to be closed and prevent it from being reused for subsequent operations.

So is it a bug? is it something else?

Comment: That would only be possible if onError() or onComplete() is not always called on register subscribers. Do you have pending requests that have not been fulfilled? Do you know which version of the protocol is used (HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2). Which type of body handlers / body subscribers are you using?

Comment: @daniel this is HTTP/1.1 and as you can see, I'm using `HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream()` body handler.

To be clear, `subscriberCompleted` is called but apparently not as fast, even though it is synchronous call.

I don't have a direct access to `HttpBodySubscriberWrapper` which has `onComplete` method

Comment: This appears to be a regression introduced in JDK 19. See https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8294916

Comment: @daniel so if I understand correctly, it says that it will be fixed in Java 20?

Comment: @daniel in addition I think the problem also exists in JDK 18 (and maybe 17, but I'm not sure)

Comment: The list of subscribers and the methods `jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl#registerSubscriber` and `jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl#subscriberCompleted` were added in 19, so if there is a leak in 18 or 17 it has a different source.